# Changing the value of a global Variable in python

Tags: python, variables

I need your help. I have assigned two global variables and I have to change their value inside their class, just take yourself a look:

```
class Lebewesen(object):

    def __init__(self):
        global x
        global y
        x = randint(10, 630)
        y = randint(10, 410)

    def zeichne(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (225, 30, 0), (x, y), 2)

    def bewege(self):
        x += randint(-1, 2)
        y += randint(-1, 2)
```

But when I try the part in "bewege"(german for 'move'), I'm assigning two new local variables, don't I? So how do I can change the value of the global x and y? With a return Function?

Answer (score 5):

When you use the global keyword you are saying you want to **use** the global versions of the variable (not set them to be global), so in your init you are changing the globals as you said you want to but in you bewege you are changing the local variable as you haven't specified you want to use the global variables.

Instead try:

```
def bewege(self):
    global x,y
    x += randint(-1, 2)
    y += randint(-1, 2)
```

Alternatively (and better practice to) make the variables attributes of your object using self like so:

```
class Lebewesen(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = randint(10, 630)
        self.y = randint(10, 410)

    def zeichne(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (225, 30, 0), (x, y), 2)

    def bewege(self):
        self.x += randint(-1, 2)
        self.y += randint(-1, 2)
```

And then they belong to that object in the same way the methods defined do. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should make `x` and `y` to be [attributes](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/class_attributes.html) of `Lebewesen`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.x = randint(10, 630)
    self.y = randint(10, 410)
```

Now you can access them in `zeichne` and `bewege` through `self.x` and `self.y`:

```
def zeichne(self):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (225, 30, 0), (self.x, self.y), 2)

def bewege(self):
    self.x += randint(-1, 2)
    self.y += randint(-1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.x = randint(10, 630)
    self.y = randint(10, 410)
```